# a problem with OCD and i dont know a lot of things about islam

Tags: halal-haram, shirk

i have been dealing with OCD about shirk for a month now and i have been diagnosed with it yesterday. i just have one question, i was dreaming and i woke up and the man in the dream was saying something shirk and when i woke up i continued the dream and continued what the man was saying, though i didn’t believe in it and i didn’t speak the things he said. is this shirk?
Also another question.
i have this habit of thinking whatever i do is shirk so one time i was laying my head on the table and i had this bad thought that i was prostrating to something and right now i was talking to my dad and i was telling him what happened and before i told him the thought that i had i told myself in my head don’t say don’t say that’s shirk but i still said it anyways. is that shirk?